# Installing Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, installation

There's no guide to installing OpenLayers on the website and Google is proving fruitless.

Is there an installation file or is it just a bunch of css and js scripts?

If so, where do you paste them?

Answer (score 2):

You go to the [downloads page](https://openlayers.org/download/) and download it. You probably want the [quickstart](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) after that.